# PhpStorm settings are lost

Tags: php, angular, phpstorm

Every single time I create new project in Angular my PhpStorm loses its settings about punctuation (single quoted imports) and tabs. I've tried to set up Default scheme but it doesn't help and I have to configure my PhpStorm every single time I've started new project.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: What happens with new projects created *outside* of Angular?

Comment: Don't know since I'm working with Angular only

Comment: Well we sure as pie don't know..... which of us do you think can find the answer? If the case is an issue with Angular and PhpStorm, or if it's with your install of PhpStorm that's a vital difference to outline.....

Comment: Can't help with the issue, been using PHPstorm for quite a while but never had that issue. As a workaround you should be able to import your settings instead of changing everything manually. Set up the editor as you please. File -> export settings. Then the next time you're coding just do file -> import settings. It's not perfect but it (should) work

Comment: Are your settings IDE or project specific?

Comment: @waterloomatt projects. But as I know new project should use default settings(at least) which are also set up. But it goes in its own way.

Comment: Why not create IDE-wide Code Style and use it? You can import it into a project (so it will become project specific) at any time if needed. Other than that -- need more info (where and how you have defined your "defaults" etc) -- screenshots are welcome. Right now I'm not sure if it's a bug or not-yet-implemented feature.